# GoogleFinance formula to find previous historical trading day of a stock

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, stock, google-finance

I have been searching for a solid formula to find stock prices of "previous trading days" of a large batch of historical dates.

The formula I started with:

```
=googlefinance(A5, "close", B5-1)
```

where A5 refers to a ticker, and B5 refers to a date in the past.

I get #NA results for previous days that fall on weekends or holidays.

I need a formula that will work reliably for 365 days per year, no matter the day of the week or number of non-trading days prior.  I have tried something like this:

```
=index(googlefinance(A5, "close", (B5-1)-2,2),2,2)
```

That formula works if the B5 date is the first trading day of the week, but not if it falls anywhere midweek.

I tried using `WORKDAY(B5,-1)` in a few ways but I realize that function can only calculate a number of workdays, not produce a date.

I need a formula that I do not have to edit and adjust cell by cell.

Comment: I tried the formula from the documentation `GOOGLEFINANCE("NASDAQ:GOOG", "close", DATE(2014,1,1), DATE(2014,12,31), "DAILY")` and it returns all the days, including the holidays. Can you show which date format are you using in B5 and prior?

Comment: The format I am using in the date cells is: 2020-04-27

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way that gives

- the closing price of the date if it was a trading-day
- the closing price of the previous trading day, if it was not a trading day.

  `=vlookup(B5+16/24,googlefinance(A5, "close", B5-7, 7),2,true)`

Here is how it works:

- `googlefinance(A5, "close", B5-7, 7)` gets the data for 7 trading days starting from the date 7 days ago.
- `vlookup` get the close price on the date closest to the date in B5 if B5 is a non-trading day.
- `B5 + 16/24` is to match the date with the closing price date stamp of 4pm.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Tested the formula above.  Produced the same problem result as some other formulas.  That is, for an original date like 2020-04-27, the formula returns the closing price of 2020-04-27, and not the previous trading day of 2020-04-24.

Comment: Made an adjustment to your formula above, and it seems to work as intended.  I think you had the right idea but might have made a typo.  The working version of your formula seems to be: `=vlookup(B5,googlefinance(A5, "close", (B5+16/24)-7, 7),2,true)`

Comment: Working formula for the closing price of the NEXT trading day, regardless of weekend or holiday: `=index(googlefinance(A5, "CLOSE", (B5+16/24)+1,2),2,2)`

Answer (score 0):

I needed to sample some recent securities price data (for a list of tickers) at even, but adjustable, intervals, over as many trading days as required. Here is what I came up with, largely thanks to the guidance of Jared G. First, I used the DATE function to make sure I had a correct internal representation of the "notional start date."

[image: Code for notional start date:]

Second, I coded the answers to two needful questions:

[image: Start date not on Sa or Su:]

[image: Start date not on Su:]

D9 is the notional start date.

Then, I coded an offset, in days, between the notional start date and the analysis start date. That fixes things up if the notional start date falls on a Saturday, Sunday or Monday, but may fail in the event of a Friday holiday:

[image: Offset:]

D10 and D11 are the two booleans.

So, now we are in a position to identify every nth trading date before the analysis start date using expressions like this:

[image: Calculation of dates:]

$D$12 is the backward offset in days from yesterday. $D$3 is the time increment, h, in days. 2 is for the 3rd date (second previous) in the series of five dates (0, 1, 2, 3, 4).

The prices are found in this way:

[image: Price calculation:]

$A18 is the ticker symbol. J$17 is the date we just calculated.

The NYSE has published all of their holidays through the end of 2026. I put that data on the next sheet, named 'NYSE Holidays,' looking like this:

[image: NYSE Holidays:]

So, we get a series of dates evenly spaced over as many past trading days as are needed, pull the corresponding price data and display it using the INDEX function.

If someone could figure out how to deal with Friday holidays, I would be grateful.